# Adding rows to pandas dataframe with date range, created_at and today, python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, expand

I have a dataframe [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNrlw.png) consisting of two columns, customer_id and a date column, created_at.

I wish to add another row for each month the customer remains in the customer base.

For example, if the customer_id was created during July, the dataframe would add 4 additional rows for that customer, between the range of "created_at" and "today". For example; for customer1 I would have 9 rows, one for each month up to day, for customer2: 7 rows, and customer3: 4 rows. I was thinking of maybe something like I've copied below, with the idea of merging df with seqDates...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
df = pd.DataFrame([("customer1", "05-02-2020"), ("customer2","05-04-2020"), ("customer3","04-07-2020")], index=["1","2","3"], columns= ("customer_id","created_at"))
df["created_at"] = pd.to_datetime(df["created_at"])


# create month expansion column 
start = min(df["created_at"])
end = pd.to_datetime("today")
seqDates = pd.date_range(start, end, freq="D")
seqDates = pd.DataFrame(seqDates)
columns = ["created_at"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from dateutil import rrule, parser


outList = []
operations_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
dfDict = df.to_dict(orient='records')
for aDict in dfDict:
    created_at = aDict['created_at']
    start_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(created_at, '%d-%m-%Y').date() - 
                 relativedelta(months = 1)
    end_date   = parser.parse(str(operations_date))
    date_range = list(rrule.rrule(rrule.MONTHLY, bymonthday=1, dtstart=start_date, 
                                  until=end_date)) 
    for aDate in date_range:
        outList.append({'customer_id' : aDict['customer_id'], 'created_at' : aDate})

df = pd.DataFrame(outList)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I want to do with my dataset, thank you. An additional question though, in my dataset, I had to convert from Unix time using 
df['created_at'] = pd.to_datetime(df['created_at'], unit='s'), which gives me the format of Year-Month-Date-Timestamp (type=Timestamps.timestamps). When I create start_date, I get told 'str' object has no attribute 'date'. Do you have any idea on how to fix this, references? You can see the format in my question above in the hyperlink dataframe.

Comment: I have taken your example df only. You can use the conversion I have used for start date. Also please upvote :)